# Как можно подключиться к VPS на Ubuntu с визуализатором Xen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen

День добрый! Собственно, суть вопроса уже отражена в заголовке: я арендовал сервер на базе Ubuntu с визуализатором Xen. Используя что я теперь могу подключиться к данному серверу с компа под управлением Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Управлять линуксом:

Раз: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY

Два: http://mintty.github.io/

Кидать файлики с windows на linux (и обратно):

Раз: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla

Два: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP

Comment: Где ж Вы были полторы недели назад? ХД Уже разобрался. Я просто был уверен, что RDP на предоставляемом хосте уже настроен, чего, как понимаете, и в помине не было, оттуда и моё беспокойство хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, в СПб отдыхал. Там на ruSO вообще заходить не хотелось. А RDP можно сделать `xrdp` в помощь, только это костыль и не нужно.